# A problem on module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, module-isomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove that $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$ and $M$ are isomorphic as left $R$-mod.
**Question** Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove that $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$ and $M$ are isomorphic as left $R$-modules.

**Attempt**

- Define a map $\phi:\text{Hom}_R(R,M)\to M$ by $\phi(f)=f(1), \forall f\in \text{Hom}_R(R,M) $. This makes sense as any $R$-module map $R\to M$ is determined by where it sends $1$.
- Define a map $\psi:M\to \text{Hom}_R(R,M)$ by $\psi(m)=f_m$, makes sense as $f_m:R\to M$ $r\mapsto rm$ is a well defined homomorphism.

$$\text{Hom}_R(R,M)\longrightarrow^\phi M\longrightarrow^\psi \text{Hom}_R(R,M) .$$
$\phi o \psi(m)=\phi(\psi(m))=\phi(f_m)=f_m(1)=m=\text{id}_M(m).$

$$M\longrightarrow^\psi \text{Hom}_R(R,M)\longrightarrow^\phi M.$$
$\psi\phi(f)=\psi(f(1))=f_{f(1)}=f=\text{id}_{\text{Hom}_R(R,M)}(f).$

I just need a clarification whether this solution is correct. I don't need alternative solution I already done.

Comment: Your map $\phi$ is fine but in the definition of $\psi$ you haven't actually specified a map $R \to M$. Also, there's no need to assume that $R$ is commutative.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It is Dummit and Foote exercise where given $R$ is commutative. I am confuse with the map $\psi$. please help me out!

Comment: Just think about what you need to do to invert $\phi$. Given $m$ how do you write down an $R$-linear map $R \to M$ which takes the value $m$ at $1$? (This map is *unique*, so once you've found a candidate you know it must be the one you were looking for.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you please tell me what will be the exactly map? I am struggling for an hour.

Comment: It's $m \mapsto (r \mapsto rm)$.

Comment: please see my recent edits. Is it correct now?

Comment: Your calculation for $\phi(\psi(m)) = m$ is fine. Your calculation for $\psi(\phi(f))$ doesn't make sense; $\psi(f(1))$ is an element of $\text{Hom}_R(R, M)$ and $f(1)$ is an element of $M$.

Comment: Stuck again. How to get rid of this issue?

Comment: You need to use the definition of $\psi$. Write $f(1) = m$. What is $\psi(m)$, by definition?

Answer (score 1):

$$\psi\phi(f) = \psi(f(1)) = f_{f(1)} \stackrel{!}= f = \text{id}_{\text{Hom}_R(R,M)}(f)$$ where $(!)$ is true because $(\forall r \in R) \ f_{f(1)}(r) = rf(1) = f(r)$.

Comment: Thanks azif ! I was just thinking about it:)